# $\nabla_C f(Cu)$ where $C$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  I am trying to find the
\begin{align}
\nabla_C f(Cu)
\end{align}
where $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $u\in \mathbb{R}^k$.  In other words, we are trying to find the derivative with respect to the matrix. This  question is about chain rule for matrix differentiation.

**What I tried:**

I found some links [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) but I couldn't really follow everything.   It appears to suggest that
\begin{align}
\frac{ \partial f(Cu)}{\partial C_{ij}}={\rm tr} \left( \nabla f(Cu) \left( \frac{\partial Cu}{\partial C_{ij}} \right)^T \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \def\e{\eqalign}$
Define the $(x,g)$ vectors as
$$\e{
x &= Cu \quad\implies\quad &dx = dC\,u \\
g &= \p{f}{x} &\big({\rm gradient\,of\,}f{\rm\,wrt\,}x\big) \\
}$$
and introduce a convenient product notation for the trace using a colon, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
 \;\doteq\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
\;=\; B:A$$
This product is also defined for vectors; just treat them as rectangular matrices.

Write the differential in terms of $x$, then change the independent
variable from $x\to C$.
$$\e{
df &= g:dx \\&= g:dC\,u \\&= gu^T:dC \\
\p{f}{C} &= gu^T &\big({\rm gradient\,of\,}f{\rm\,wrt\,}C\big) \\\\
}$$
As you have discovered, the difficulty with using the chain rule in matrix calculus is that the intermediate quantities are often third and fourth order tensors, which are difficult to work with.

The nice thing about the differential approach is that the differential of a matrix acts like a matrix. In particular, it follows all of the rules of matrix algebra.

And using the trace (aka the colon product) eliminates a whole category of transposition errors, which arise with other methodologies.

Comment: Do you have some good reference book on learning this?

Comment: The standard text is probably _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus & Neudecker.

Comment: In the final answer, $g$ is evaluated at $Cu$? What I means is that the answer is $\frac{\partial f(Cu)}{\partial C}=g(Cu) u^T$, correct?

Comment: That's right, $\,g=g(x)=g(Cu)\;$