# Matrix derivative confusion

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

$f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ 
 $a=z$ 
$z=Wa'$ 
Where $a,z,a'$ are vectors of shapes $n\times 1, n\times 1, m\times 1$ and $W$ is a matrix of shape $n\times m$.
I need $\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial W}$. 

Applying chain rule, $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial W}$$
Now $\frac{\partial z}{\partial W}=a'$. The second term here is of shape $n\times n$. But $a'$ has shape $m\times 1$. So I must have committed a mistake somewhere. 
Can someone point me in the right direction? I finally want to compute the above derivative. ($\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$)

Comment: For matrix calculus, a gentle suggestion is to avoid "chain rule", see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919948/nabla-c-fcu-where-c-is-a-matrix

Comment: @user550103 I see, thanks