# derivate and chain rule about trace

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, chain-rule

suppose $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d $ with size of (1,d), and $\mathbf{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. Then how to solve the derivate of $\mathbf{x}$:
$$\begin{align}
\textrm{tr}(\ (\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})^{\prime} (\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})\ )
\end{align}$$
My steps are from chain rule:

let $L = \textrm{tr}(\ (\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})^{\prime} (\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})\ )$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\mathbf{x}}}
&=\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})}} \cdot \frac{\partial(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\\
&= 2(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{T}) \dot (2\mathbf{x}^{\prime})
\end{aligned}
$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Question : Isn't $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}$ a $d\times d$-matrix? How do you subract the $\color{red}{n}\times d$-matrix $\mathbf{T}$ from it ? Hint regarding the chain rule: Write out everything explicitly in $2\times 2.$

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for your comments!! T is $d\times d$ actually, it was a typo 

Comment: T is $d\times d$, sorry for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is symmetric, then your result is ok, but else it is a bit off. I wanted to take the chance to outline a general procedure that works fine for this kinds of problems. Hope you liked.

### The derivative

For this kind of tasks you can use the definition of the derivative. If $x$ is a row vector, and $f$ is a differentiable function that eats vectors, then the derivative $Df(x)$ of $f$ at $x$ is the linear part of the change in $f(x)$ when $x$ increases by another vector $h$. That is, $Df(x)$ is the unique vector that satisfies $\def\tr{\mathrm{tr}}$

$$f(x+h) = f(x) + h\,Df(x) + O(h^2). \tag 1$$
where $O(h^2)$ denotes the terms where $h$ appears with order $\geq 2$.

### Useful notation

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices, a useful notation is

$$ A : B = \tr(A'B) = \tr (BA') = \tr(B'A) = \tr(BA') = \sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ij}.$$

Clearly this product commutes and is unchanged when you transpose both factors.
Moreover, if $v$ is a row and $w$ a column, write
$$w : v = v : w = vw = w'v'.$$
Why? So that for row vectors $x,h$ you have the nice properties
$$x:Ah' = xA:h' = h':xA=h'x:A=A:h'x = Ah':x = \sum_{ij}x_iA_{ij}h_j$$
and still the result is unchanged when both factors are transposed.

### Now to you problem

Your $x$ are row vectors. Define $A(x)=(x'x-T)$. Then your function is
$$f(x)=A(x):A(x)$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
A(x+h)
&= (x'+h')(x+h)-T \\
&= x'x+h'x+x'h-T+O(h^2) \\
&= A(x)+h'x+x'h+O(h^2).
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align}
f(x+h)
&= A(x+h):A(x+h) \\
&= [A(x)+h'x+x'h]:[A(x)+h'x+x'h]+O(h^2) \\
&= A(x):A(x) + 2 A(x):[h'x+x'h] + O(h^2) \\
&= f(x) + 2 A(x):[h'x+x'h] + O(h^2) \\
\end{align}
$$
Now I will denote $A=A(x)$, since there will be no more $A(x+h)$.
$$
\begin{align}
f(x+h)-f(x)
&= 2[A:h'x + A:x'h] + O(h^2) \\
&= 2[A'x':h + Ax':h] + O(h^2) \\
&= 2h:(A'x' + Ax') + O(h^2) \\
&= 2h:(A' + A)x' + O(h^2) \\
\end{align}
$$
Comparing this with $(1)$, you get that
$$Df(x) = 2(A' + A)x' = 2(2x'x-T-T')x'$$

### Another way

This one is more informal, but can be quite handy. Starting by
$$f(x)=A:A$$
an taking differentials:
$$
\begin{align}
df
&= 2A:dA \\
&= 2A:d(x'x) \\
&= 2(A:dx'x + A:x'dx) \\
&= 2(A':x'dx + Ax':dx) \\
&= 2(A'x':dx + Ax':dx) \\
&= 2(A' + A)x':dx
\end{align}
$$
hence
$$\frac{df}{dx} = 2(A'+A)x'$$
as before.

Comment: wow!!!!!Thanks a lot for your kind answer!!!! thanks!!!!!

Comment: I just can't like it any more!!! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @Iris88 You're welcome. Your question also helped me review those concepts. When dealing with functions involving matrices, it appears that one should avoid the chain rule because the intermediate terms end up being higher order tensors. See e.g. greg's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919948/nabla-c-fcu-where-c-is-a-matrix).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!( again !) sry about replying so late as I didn't check out my notifications... I‘ll study the example you gave carefully, thank you very much! ! ! :)